# What could cause a thread that is receiving output from a JSch channel to hang while printing that output

Tags: jsch

Recently I found a problem with printing out large quantities of text through Jsch channel.getInputStream().

using this code:

```
outputStream_from_outputChannel = channel.getInputStream();
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(outputStream_from_outputChannel));
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null ){
    System.out.println(line);
    numOfLines++;
}
```

...sometimes (most of the time) I will get results back, but sometimes it will stop producing the printout without returning, meaning the printing will stop in the middle and the thread will hang. What do you think that might be due to? So far I found out that is not the jsch session that is timout-ing. Its timeout is set to 0.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first if the stream is ready\available:

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (outputStream_from_outputChannel.available() > 0) {
    int i = is.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if (i < 0)
        break;
    someStrBuff.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reading from channel input stream hangs if remote server stops responding (due to reasons such as network connectivity, overload etc) but streams readline method blocks forever. Solution to the problem is to set server alive interval using :

```
session.setServerAliveInterval(int milliseconds);
```

It will send piggyback packets in order to check connectivity after specified time interval. And readline will return if no response is received from server when checking for connectivity.